# Determine Amicable Pairs within Confines of Theta(n)

Tags: c++, performance, coding-efficiency

I am attempting to implement a program that reads a positive integer from the user and outputs all the perfect numbers between 2 and `userNum`.  It also outputs all the pairs of amicable numbers that are between 2 and `userNum`.  Both numbers must be within the range.  I am seriously struggling with this.

**Requirements:**
1) calls to `AnalyzeDivisors` must be kept to theta(userNum) times all together.  2) Function `void AnalyzeDivisors` must take the following arguments `int num, int& outCountDivs, int& outSumDivs`.  3) Function `bool IsPerfect` must take the following argument `int num`.

I am honestly at a loss for how to do this within that efficiency range. I currently am able to determine all the perfect numbers in the range by bending the rules as far as parameters to the IsPerfect Function, but how can I determine amicable pairs without calling Analyze Dividors an inordinate amount of times each iteration of the for loop in main?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Code below:

**main**

```
int main()
{
    int userNum;

    //Request number input from the user
    cout << "Please input a positive integer num (>= 2): " << endl;
    cin >> userNum;

    for (int counter = 2; counter <= userNum; counter++)
    {
        //Set variables 
        int outCountDivs = 0, outSumDivs = 0, otherAmicablePair = 0;
        bool perfectNum = false, isAmicablePair = false;

        //Analyze dividors
        AnalyzeDividors(counter, outCountDivs, outSumDivs);

        //determine perfect num
        perfectNum = IsPerfect(counter, outSumDivs);

        if (perfectNum)
            cout << endl << counter << IS_PERFECT_NUM;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

**AnalyzeDividors**

```
void AnalyzeDividors(int num, int& outCountDivs, int& outSumDivs)
{
    int divisorCounter;

    for (divisorCounter = 1; divisorCounter <= sqrt(num); divisorCounter++)
    {
        if (num % divisorCounter == 0 && num / divisorCounter != divisorCounter && num / divisorCounter != num)
        {
            //both counter and num/divisorCounter
            outSumDivs += divisorCounter + (num / divisorCounter);
            outCountDivs += 2;
        }

        else if ((num % divisorCounter == 0 && num / divisorCounter == divisorCounter) || num/divisorCounter == num)
        {
            //Just divisorCounter
            outSumDivs += divisorCounter;
            outCountDivs += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**IsPerfect**

```
bool IsPerfect(int userNum, int outSumDivs)
{

    if (userNum == outSumDivs)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote please let me know why so I can attempt to rectify the issue with the post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution that fits the requirements. I found amicable numbers by storing every number and sum of divisors in a map. If a number's sum of divisors is entered in the map, and the sum of divisor's sum of divisors was the current number, then they are amicable.

Because the results are saved each time, you only call `AnalyzeDivisors` once per number.

Pardon the lazy variable naming.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>

void AnalyzeDivisors(int num, int& divc, int &divs)
{
    divc = 1;
    divs = 1;
    for (int x = 2, y = std::sqrt(num); x <= y; ++x)
    {
        if (num % x == 0)
        {
            ++divc;
            divs += x;
            if (num / x != x)
            {
                ++divc;
                divs += num / x;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool IsPerfect(int num)
{
    static std::map<int, int> amicable;
    int divc = 0, divs = 0;
    AnalyzeDivisors(num, divc, divs);
    if (amicable.find(divs) != amicable.end() && amicable[divs] == num)
        std::cout << num << " and " << divs << " are best bros for life.\n";
    amicable[num] = divs;
    return num == divs;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    std::cout << "Pick a number: ";
    std::cin >> num;
    for (int x = 2; x < num; ++x)
    {
        if (IsPerfect(x))
            std::cout << x << " is perfect in every way!\n";
    }
}
```